# Iterate through 2d array looking at neighbours, except at boundaries

Tags: python, arrays, python-3.x, loops, iteration

I have this code where I'm  trying to iterate through a 2d (numpy) array of dims 300,350.
I'm looking at each point [i,j] in the array and then looking at its two neighbours [i+1, j+1] etc (depending on angles). I'm looking at the angles 0, 45, 90 and 135 degrees. My problem is indexing as for the first i,j (angle = 0 degrees) i'll be looking at i,j+1 and i,j-1.
Since the first iteration is at j = 0 I get an indexing error, because j-1 = -1. I have been trying and searching for hours now on how to circumvent this. My code looks something like this:

```
for i in range(trex.shape[0]): # ALL ROWS
    for j in range(trex.shape[1]): # ALL COLUMNS
        if shape[i,j] == 0:    # for 0 degree angles (shape is angles)
            if trex[i,j] > trex[i, j+1] and trex[i,j] > trex[i,j-1]: # conditions
                np.append(trex_other, trex[i,j])
            else:
                np.append(trex_other, 0)
```

I look at all the angles but this is just an example of what I want it to do. To summarize I want to iterate through this 2d array at all points except the boundaries all around the 2d array.
Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: What are you trying to do, when your indexing works? There is probably a better numpy solution that vectorizes your function. I would also add the tag `numpy` instead of the generic `arrays` tag to attract the right people.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Iterate from 1 to the length-1

```
for i in range(1, trex.shape[0]-1): # MOST ROWS
    for j in range(1, trex.shape[1]-1): # MOST COLUMNS
           ...
```